# Using Symbolic C++ library : Ho to print Matrix output description in objective c? As i have added two matrix.Code is given below.Thanks

Tags: c++

How to get description of mp3 matrix?

```
Matrix<int> mp2= Matrix<int>(2, 2);

mp2[0][0]=_arr[0][0];   
mp2[0][1]=_arr[0][1];
mp2[1][0]=_arr[1][0];
mp2[1][1]=_arr[1][1];

Matrix<int> mp1= Matrix<int>(2, 2);

mp1[0][0]=1;
mp1[0][1]=2;
mp1[1][0]=3;
mp1[1][1]=4;
```

Matrix mp3= Matrix(3, 3);

mp3=mp1+mp2;

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you want to add the two Matrix's together? You can iterate like this:

```
Matrix<int> mp3 = Matrix<int>(2, 2);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
   {
        mp3[i][j] = mp1[i][j] + mp2[i][j];
   }
}
```